# unexpected character { at line 1

Tags: xml, macos, plist

I created a plist that run a junk mail mark as read every so often but there seems to be a problem with the file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN”\”http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
   <key>Label</key>
   <string>com.junkread.test</string>
   <key>ProgramArguments</key>
   <array>
   <string>/Applications/junk.read.app/Contents/MacOS/Application\ Stub </string>
   </array>
   <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
   <dict>
      <key>seconds</key>
      <integer>30</integer>
   </dict>
   </dict>
   </plist>
```

when I run plutil  `% plutil /Library/LaunchAgents/com.junkread.test.plist`
I get the following error "unexpected character { at line 1"

I would appreciate your help

Comment: The file doesn't seem to have the `{` character, are you sure it's this file? or is there more to this file?

Comment: It looks like you saved the data in JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the file format to .txt

Open the file and hit shortcut Shift-Cmd-T or, on Apple's top menu, click Format then Make Plain Text.

2. Change it back to .plist by renaming the file to end with .plist